# What is the best way of implementing expiration semantics on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Presently I am using Redis as a data store, it all goes well until it doesn't namely we have records that suddenly disappear but there's no rhyme or reason we can find it and it's generally one offs.  I understand it is rare and Redis is not considered durable so I am trying to find an approach that provides me similar speed for reads but not necessarily for writes *as a contingency if we can't find the reason why data is being lost on a Redis **cluster** that makes things a little harder to find as well*.

As for data usage, it's primarily storing session tokens with a very short expiration times of say 5 minutes for the access token and 15 days for the refresh token with rollover (that is if I refresh the data that exists changes its expiration by another 15 days).

The idea I had was to implement an JPA L2 cache on top of a MySQL server.  That way I get the benefit of fast reads.

The potential problem I am contemplating which is the reason why I had used Redis is the expiration logic.

So what I am thinking is that even if I query and get slightly more data I can always filter out the ones that are expired as necessary.  (That's because I am trying to utilize the L2 cache so I may be querying by blocks of time rather than using the current to improve cache hits for the query cache).

The delete part is a bit tricky for me, but I am thinking of doing deletes by doing a simple `where expires_on < current timestamp` on an hourly basis.

I'm looking for something specifically in MySql 5.7 as I am using Aurora Serverless RDS

Comment: Just to address your Redis issue, it sounds like `maxmemory-policy` is configured in a way allowing Redis to remove keys before their `TTL` is up when you have memory pressure. If that's the case then you probably want to look at how much memory each of your redis cluster nodes can use.

Comment: agreed, we set it up to free up which would explain the data loss, but we can't find it in the AWS Monitoring any indication that the memory of a node becomes full.

Comment: Can you describe those tokens further?

Comment: Basically simple JSON objects or references to them that would be sent back as is to the client as is.  So I'd likely store them into a CLOB.

Comment: How about running a Lambda on a 5 minute timer, to execute the delete you described?

Comment: Another solution is to use a [MySQL EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html), but I have no idea if Aurora Serverless supports events. It's possible they disable the event scheduler, since it's serverless it might not be something that can be supported. I mean, if the db instance is serverless, it might be offline when the event is supposed to execute, right? Something for you to research, or contact AWS support.

Comment: At least on V1 it does not appear that MySQL event is supported on serverless https://tech.ilionx.com/why-the-mysql-event-scheduler-doesnt-work-on-aurora-serverless-and-how-to-fix-it-with-aws-lambda/